# Need to exclude my java.exe from anti-virus scan.

Tags: antivirus

I know, it can be done by anti-virus exclusion list. But I need to do with my java code.
Is there any possibility to do this?
Will anti-virus allow to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also tell me if there is any way to know my java.exe was under anti-virus scan

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, Anti-Virus software's job is not to be disabled by the software they have to observe.

And since Java has proven to be such a security risk over the last months, there's really no reason to do so. So: Obvious answer is: NO. No sane anti-virus software will let you disable it. That would be plain stupid.

Also, no anti-virus software will offer an easy interface for your software to ask "have I been scanned yet"; again, that would be stupid from a security point of view (also, it's not how Antivirus works at all).

PS: If you're planning to do security research by getting to know about writing viruses, I don't think you should start with Java -- Java's original intent was to be hard to abuse, so it's hard to do for a beginner (but due to bad design and implementation, there's many opportunities for abuse by experts).

There is **plenty** of literature out there on penetration testing, software security (from both sides of the problem) and so on. Don't start from scratch. Get a good book.

Comment: I don't want to write any viruses. My Service is slowing down because of anti-virus. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @AravindharajG under no circumstances then is disabling anti-virus the right choice.

Comment: That's what I am asking. I need to ask the user to disable the antivirus. This is currently I am doing. So is there any way to do this automatically (after getting permission from user like getting credential)

Comment: Any way thanks for your reply . .  .

Comment: @AravindharajG: you didn't get my point. This is 2015. 99.5% of things that would ask a user to disable their antivirus are either malicious or from the last decade, where "shortly" disabling antivirus was an option. Asking a user to deactivate the virus scanner on java.exe is like asking a bank to always leave the safe door open. Only irresponsible banks would do that.

Comment: @AravindharajG: In this time and age, asking a user to disable their Antivirus is both a bad idea and won't help, because no user who knows what they're doing will do that. Especially not on a corporate network, unless they want to be fired.

Comment: ok fine. Thanks for your advise